# Getting TFS identity user's mailaddress for C# VS2012 and VS2013

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm having issues getting the TFS user's MailAddress property for VS2013.  Previously, I was using the IGroupSecurityServiceInterface to obtain the MailAddress, but that method is now obsolete, since VS2012.  I can successfully obtain the SID, but once I have that, I am getting stuck getting the MailAddress of that particular user.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
//Establish Connection to TFS
Uri _tfsUri = new Uri("http://tfsurl:8080/tfs");
TfsConfigurationServer _tfsConfigServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(_tfsUri, new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));
_tfsConfigServer.EnsureAuthenticated();
if(!_tfsConfigServer.HasAuthenticated)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Unable to authenticate");
}
IIdentityManagementService _ims = _tfsConfigServer.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

//Get Members of Group Interested in

IdentityDescriptor[] _membersGroup = _ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[DefaultCollection]\\MemberGroup", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource).Members;

//Obtain MailAddress
foreach (IdentityDescriptor _individualMember in _membersGroup)
{
     //Get SID for individual
     string _SID = _individualMember.Identifier.ToString();

     //Get MailAddress

}
```

////////////////UPDATE/////////////////////////////////////

I was actually able to get the email addresses doing a different approach:

```
TeamFoundationIdentity _usersGroup = _ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[DefaultCollection]\\MemberGroup", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);
TeamFoundationIdentity[] _groupMembers = _ims.ReadIdentitites(_usersGroup.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
foreach(TeamFoundationIdentity _member in _groupMembers)
{
    string _mailAddress = _member.GetAttribute("Mail", null);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using LDAP and querying active directory using their SID and or Login name instead?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that.  Maybe that'd work instead.  I was hoping to use TeamFoundation functionality entirely.  Since Microsoft made IGroupSecurtiyService obsolete, I was hoping that I was overlooking the property, or the method, but no such luck.  With IGroupSecurityService, I was doing something like this to obtain the MailAddress:
`code`    IGroupSecurityService _gss = (IGroupSecurityService)tfs.GetServices(typeof(IgroupSecurityService));
   `code` string _mailAddress = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, _SID, QueryMembership.None).MailAddress;

I was hoping for equivalent w/ VS2012/2013

Comment: I've never used those, but I have used LDAP before :)

Comment: is it just under LDAP namespace? Or is it something else? I'll see if that can at least get me past this point.

Comment: Try System.DirectoryServices namespace

Comment: Solved it another way using TeamFoundation :) I added it to my original post